# Amazon ELB and SSL Certificate IP address requirement

Tags: ssl, ip

I started setting up Amazon's ELB Service for my server. We have one nodejs server behind the ELB and 2 mongoDB Servers. I want to get SSL certificate for my domain api.mysite.com that A record with Alias to ELB Address (set in router53). I know that we must have static ip address for SSL certificate but the ELB address maybe change. so I want to know that:

1. should I get elastic IP for my nodejs server?
2. If I shutdown the nodejs server and change the IP of nodejs server, Is SSL still works or not? What should I do?
3. Should I change my DNS Setting?

Answer (score 3):

Certificates do not require a Static IP. They don't even require their own IP, this is only encouraged because about 15% of the Internet still doesn't support SNI.

Certificates only require that whatever the user enters in the URL is part of the the Subject Name (usually the Common Name, but it's a long story).

So you need:

- A certificate that points to api.example.com
- A DNS record that point api.example.com to an IP on your server (doesn't matter if it's ELB, Elastic IP, whatever you would type into your computer to hit your server).
- A server responding to requests directed at that IP, which has the certificate's matching private key.

Comment: Is there source for the percentage quoted?

Comment: @user Basically, the percentage without SNI support is the folks using IE on Windows XP.

Comment: WinXP is the biggest culprit lacking SNI Support (with IE or Chrome only; others work) and still [holds about 20% market share as of writing](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php). Many on XP do have Firefox or Safari, and XP users tend to "consume" Internet content less than those with newer OSes, so on the whole 15% is a good ballpark number. Every website is different of course, different users/target audience. A quick hard number, my blog saw 14 WinXP/IE browsers out of 1000 in the last quarter.

Comment: Yep [completely agree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#No_support). I just thought there might be a nice study/survey done on the matter, that quotes a percentage, that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that we must have static ip address for SSL certificate

No, you don't. Install the SSL on the ELB and you're good to go.